# Как заставить casperjs ждать конца отработки ajax?

Tags: javascript, парсер, phantomjs, casperjs

Приветствую! Проблема такая. на странице есть некоторый элемент

```
<div class="someclass">text1</div>
```

При загрузке страницы срабатывает javascript и значение text1 заменяется на другое значение text2, которое приходит в виде json. Проблема состоит в том, что casperjs находит значение text1, не дожидаясь когда отработает javascript, а мне нужно значение text2. Подскажите, есть ли такая возможность в casper заставить его ждать, пока не появится text2 и подскажите как это делается, куда двигаться или где почитать об этом? Значения содержимых text1 и text2 заранее не известны.

Comment: Как вариант можете поставить таймер. Смотрите сколько примерно времени нужно и ставите таймер на выполнение.https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval

Comment: Таймер стоит, но дело в том, что иногда видимо интернет начинает тормозить и времени не хватает, не хочется ставить сильно большое время, не всегда это будет оправдано, хочется более гибкого решения

Comment: Прикрепите к вопросу код, так будет понятнее.

Comment: а что мешает использовать промисы ? Или раз ответ приходит извне в виде json, то наверняка это ajax запрос. Прикрутите обработчик casperjs в функцию .done(function(d){}) http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ или .then(function(){}) (для промисов) https://learn.javascript.ru/promise. В таком случае ненужно будет настраивать лишние таймеры - обработчик будет вызван только тогда, когда text2 будет загружен

Comment: Спасибо, alexoander, про промисы не знал, попробую решить вопрос с помощью промисов

Comment: Посмотрите в документации:

Дождаться загрузки ресурса -
 http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforresource .

Дождаться появления элемента на странице - http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforselector